# Export artboards from a page in sketch

Tags: export, sketch-app

Is it possible to easily export all the artboards from a single page in Sketch, without manually selecting each artboard in the Export dialog (or deselecting the artboard from other pages)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Screencast of collapsing all Artboards and Groups in the layer list in Sketch 3]

## Yes You Can :)

Currently, the easiest way is to go up to the Menu bar:

`View > Layer List > Collapse Artboards and Groups`

From there, you can select all the Artboards on the page WITHOUT selecting any of the layers.